# Выделение адреса в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в следующем предложении:

*7 июня по адресу: г. Омск, ул. Красный Путь, 6, актовый зал — состоится заседание Межведомственной комиссии*.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ переделал.

Начать-то надо было с двоеточия и тире. 
Да, я полагаю, что такая пунктуация возможна.

По поводу двоеточия. Оно факультативно, но вполне здесь уместно.

> Вопрос № 267344 Добрый день. Извините, что повторяюсь, но очень нужно
>   получить ответ. Огромная к вам просьба. Пожалуйста, дайте однозначный
>   ответ, нужно ли ставить двоеточие после слов «по адресу», то есть по
>   адресу: ул. такая-то или по адресу ул. такая-то? У вас во всех ста
>   ответах на этот запрос – разнобой. Если постановка знака
>   факультативна, то какие причины влияют на его появление? Буду очень
>   признательна за конкретный ответ. Рина И.
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка Здесь двоеточие - чисто
>   технический знак, оно визуально отделяет адрес от остального текста.
>   Двоеточие ставится, если адрес синтаксически не является частью
>   предложения. Ср.: По адресу Морская, 17 ведутся ремонтные работы.
>   (Здесь "по адресу" - обстоятельство места.) За справками обращайтесь
>   по адресу: Морская, 17.

Что качается тире, то это тоже естественный "отбивающий" адрес от остальной части предложения. Строго говоря, там обычно стоит запятая.

> Добрый день! Нужна ли запятая после окончания указанного адреса в
>   предложении: "На обращение от 11.04.2017 № ______ по вопросу о
>   приведении фасадов здания по адресу: Москва, ул. Ленина, д. 5, лит. А
>   (нужна здесь запятая или нет?)в надлежащее состояние в рамках
>   подготовки к проведению спортивно-праздничных мероприятий сообщаю
>   следующее." И какое правило можно применить в данном случае. Заранее
>   благодарю.
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Запятая нужна.

Но если выбрано тире (а тире вполне возможно использовать для членения предложения), то запятую надо опустить. Если уж очень строго хотите подойти к делу, то во избежание недоразумений ставьте запятую. Но я бы к тире не придрался, оно нагляднее.

> Омск, ул. Красный Путь, 6, актовый зал

У Вас все правильно. Запятые обязательны. Единственное, что Номер дома в русской традиции чаще указывается с сокращением "д."

***Омск, ул. Красный Путь, д. 6, актовый зал***

Это рекомендация действует для адресов на конвертах, юридических и тому подобных, там где некоторая стандартизация естественна и желательно.

Но для объявления подобного типа сойдет и без "д.", тем более, что в адресе нет квартиры.
Примеры - тут.
http://delo-press.ru/articles.php?n=5441

Итого:
***7 июня по адресу: г. Омск, ул. Красный Путь, 6, актовый зал, состоится заседание Межведомственной комиссии***

Или с тире, тоже считаю возможным.

Для сомневающихся и недоумевающих.

> Пример 6 Дмитровское ш., 125, стр. 1, офис 5
>
> Нужно сказать, что в настоящее время часто в адресе не указывают
>   обозначение дома –«д.», а пишут только его номер. Такой способ
>   написания используется в зарубежных странах, он допускается и в
>   российской практике адресования корреспонденции. 
>   См. Пример 6.

(ссылка на источник - выше.)

Добавляю. Совет от Сержа не "выделять" номер дома (или что он там подумал) считаю вредным и противоречащим примерам, им же приведенным.

Comment: Вот вы сейчас клевещете. Я не писал, что ***не надо выделять номер дома***, это,как всегда, ваши выдумки. Слово "дом'' в моем ответе нет. Я писал, что непонятно, к чему относится цифра, поэтому не стоит выделять.  Это две разные вещи.

Comment: @Серж, Это все разговоры ни о чем. По сути давайте. Вы всё еще полагаете, что "выделять" не надо? Кому интересно, что вам там непонятно. Я не могу представить, что взрослому человеку непонятно, что цифра после названия улицы - номер дома. Но даже если так, почему не "выделять"-то?

Comment: Вы так увлеклись выделением номера дома, что никак не прокомментировали двоеточие и тире (на мой взгляд, пунктуация не тривиальная, требует пояснений)

Comment: @М_Г, тьфу, черт, а ведь верно, спасибо. Вопрос-то был не в этом...

Answer (score 0):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно. *По адресу* выступает здесь в роли обобщающего слова.

§ 160. Двоеточие ставится перед перечислением, находящимся в середине предложения, если перечислению предшествует обобщающее слово или слова *как-то, например, а именно*…
О тире после перечисления, стоящего в середине предложения после двоеточия, см. § 174, п. 3, примечание. 
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire

Answer (score 0):

Вариант первый:
...*г. Омск, ул. Красный Путь 6, актовый зал*...
Возникает некая двусмысленность: улица становится очень похожей на шестой Красный Путь.

Вариант второй:
*...г. Омск, ул. Красный Путь, 6, актовый зал...*
Так тоже возможно, но цифра "шесть" совсем теряется между "Путем" и "актовым залом".
Есть много адресов, которые всем известны, и номера домов в них отделены запятой: Петровка, 38; Огарева, 6; Литейный, 4...

Вариант третий:
*...г. Омск, ул. Красный Путь, д.6, актовый зал...*
Вот в этом случае - всё всем понятно и соответствует правилам.

***7 июня по адресу: г. Омск, ул. Красный Путь, д.6, актовый зал — состоится заседание Межведомственной комиссии.***

**Дополнение**
Что-то я засомневалась, обнаружив следующие примеры:

*8 июня 2017 года в 10-00 часов в лекционном зале по адресу: г. Саранск, ул. Коммунистическая, д. 35 (1 этаж), состоится обучающий семинар по ведению регистра...*

*С 11 по 14 мая 2017 года по адресу: г. Москва, Тишинская пл., д.1, состоится 9-я Международная специализированная выставка – продажа «ГРАНД ТЕКСТИЛЬ»!*

*16 марта по адресу: Москва, Тверская, 22, отель InterContinental состоится двенадцатая ежегодная конференция «Снабжение в нефтегазовом комплексе» (Нефтегазснаб-2017).*

*16 марта 2017 года по адресу г. Чита, ул. Амурская, 68, состоится заседание коллегии Министерства финансов Забайкальского края.*

Но Ваша пунктуация не противоречит никаким правилам, все четко и ясно.

Answer (score 0):

Поискал в Нацкорпусе примеры с двоеточием (*по адресу:... состоится*), получил 7 вхождений. Отбросим первое как неудачное и увидим, что нет ни запятой, ни тире.

> Результаты поиска в газетном корпусе
>   адрес  dat  bcolon
>   на расстоянии от 1 до 10 от состояться
>   Найдено 7 документов, 7 вхождений.
>
> 1.Андрей ГРЕЧАННИК. Lamborghini вернулась в Россию // Комсомольская правда, 2012.04.13   [омонимия не снята]  Все примеры (1) 
>    Официальное открытие нового автосалона Lamborghini в Москве **по адресу:** Кутузовский проспект 1/7, **состоится** в этом году. [Андрей ГРЕЧАННИК. Lamborghini вернулась в Россию // Комсомольская правда, 2012.04.13]  [омонимия не снята]  ←…→
>
> 2.Надежда РЖЕВСКАЯ. Через три года Калининград забудет об угольных котельных // Комсомольская правда, 2010.05.16   [омонимия не снята]  Все примеры (1) 
>    17 мая в 15 часов в МУК КТК «Дом искусств» **по адресу:** Ленинский проспект, 155 **состоятся** публичные слушания по отчету об исполнении бюджета городского округа «Город Калининград» за 2009 год. [Надежда РЖЕВСКАЯ. Через три года Калининград забудет об угольных котельных // Комсомольская правда, 2010.05.16]  [омонимия не снята]  ←…→
>
> 3.26 и 27 апреля 2007 г. ожидаются следующие события (Пермский край) // Новый регион 2, 2007.04.26   [омонимия не снята]  Все примеры (1) 
>    В 14 часов **по адресу:** Сибирская, 1в Агентстве по физкультуре и спорту Пермского края **состоится** пресс-конференция. [26 и 27 апреля 2007 г. ожидаются следующие события (Пермский край) // Новый регион 2, 2007.04.26]  [омонимия не снята]  ←…→
>
> 4.24 и 25 ноября 2005 года ожидаются следующие события (Пермская область) // Новый регион 2, 2005.11.24   [омонимия не снята]  Все примеры (1) 
>    В 15-00 **по адресу:** Куйбышева, 14, малый зал (4 этаж) **состоится** награждение победителей регионального конкурса в рамках Всероссийского конкурса программы «100 лучших товаров России». [24 и 25 ноября 2005 года ожидаются следующие события (Пермская область) // Новый регион 2, 2005.11.24]  [омонимия не снята]  ←…→
>
> 5.23 и 24 ноября 2005 года ожидаются следующие события (Пермская область) // Новый регион 2, 2005.11.23   [омонимия не снята]  Все примеры (1) 
>    В 15-00 **по адресу**: Куйбышева, 14, малый зал (4 этаж) **состоится** награждение победителей регионального конкурса в рамках Всероссийского конкурса программы «100 лучших товаров России». [23 и 24 ноября 2005 года ожидаются следующие события (Пермская область) // Новый регион 2, 2005.11.23]  [омонимия не снята]  ←…→
>
> 6.25 и 26 июня 2004 года ожидаются следующие события (Пермская область) // Новый регион 2, 2004.06.25   [омонимия не снята]  Все примеры (1) 
>    В 10-00 **по адресу**: проспект Ленина, 8 **состоится** церемония открытия мемориальной доски памяти поэта Алексея Решетова. [25 и 26 июня 2004 года ожидаются следующие события (Пермская область) // Новый регион 2, 2004.06.25]  [омонимия не снята]  ←…→
>
> 7.25 и 26 марта 2004 года ожидаются следующие события (Пермская область) // Новый регион 2, 2004.03.25   [омонимия не снята]  Все примеры (1) 
>    В 14.30 **по адресу**: пр-т Парковый, 40 А **состоится** торжественная сдача дома для семей милиционеров. [25 и 26 марта 2004 года ожидаются следующие события (Пермская область) // Новый регион 2, 2004.03.25]  [омонимия не снята]  ←…→

Answer (score -1):

Названия адресов относятся к уточняющим обстоятельствам и выделятся запятыми.

Корректно: 7 июня по адресу: г. Омск, ул. Красный Путь,актовый зал...

Только непонятно, к чему относится цифра 6. Ее выделять в любом случае не нужно.

> Ср.: В деревне Уваровке, Петровского района, Калужской области, состоялся праздник урожая; Посёлок Новые Горки, Щёлковского района, Московской области, находится недалеко от станции Болшево; Москва, улица Плющиха, д. 38, кв. 2.

[Розенталь. Д. Э. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118)

Comment: *Только непонятно, к чему относится цифра 6. Ее выделять в любом случае не нужно.* - Серж, это номер дома. Вы никогда не жили в городе, где на улице больше одного дома? Так я вам скажу, что Красный Путь - это огромная улица, домов не одна сотня, если память не изменяет.

Comment: Ну тогда не лучше написать: д. 6.

Comment: Тем не менее "вредный совет" ("не выделять") остался.