# Помогите, пожалуйста, с пунктуацией

Tags: пунктуация

Фотосессия "5 простых шагов".
Её цель — показать Вам, каким легким может быть сотрудничество с ведущим. Выражаю благодарность Виктору и Анастасии Шукмановым за участие, ресторану Анданте (по адресу Мытнинская набережная, дом 3) в лице Игнатенковой Натальи за предоставленную площадку и фотографу Дмитрию Модестову за проделаную работу.

Answer (score 2):

> за проделаную работу.

Исправьте здесь (нужно добавить вторую -н-):

**за проделанную работу.**

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения пунктуации у меня нет уверенности только в одном: нужно ли ставить двоеточие после слов "по адресу". По-моему, оба варианта  допустимы.

> [Вопрос № 267344](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=267344)
>   Добрый день. Извините, что повторяюсь, но очень нужно получить ответ. Огромная к вам просьба. Пожалуйста, дайте однозначный ответ, нужно ли ставить двоеточие после слов «по адресу», то есть по адресу: ул. такая-то или по адресу ул. такая-то? У вас во всех ста ответах на этот запрос – разнобой. Если постановка знака факультативна, то какие причины влияют на его появление? Буду очень признательна за конкретный ответ. Рина И.
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Здесь двоеточие - чисто технический знак, оно визуально отделяет адрес от остального текста. Двоеточие ставится, если адрес синтаксически не является частью предложения. Ср.: По адресу Морская, 17 ведутся ремонтные работы. (Здесь "по адресу" - обстоятельство места.) За справками обращайтесь по адресу: Морская, 17.

Подробная дискуссия здесь: [Выделение адреса в предложении](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432312/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8).